# MySQL Query to remove zero columns

Tags: mysql

MySQL query to remove all the columns from a table having sum of amount equal to zero

I have a table like this

```
Date   Col 1   Col 2 Col 3  Col 4   Col 5
1/1/15      0   0      1      0      0
1/2/15      1   0      0      0      0
1/3/15      1   0      1      1      0
1/4/15      1   0      1      1      0
```

I want to get the out put table having the output data as given below

```
Date     col 1     col 3     col 4
1/1/15    1       1           1        
1/2/15    0       0           1      
1/3/15    0       1           0      
1/4/15    1       1           1
```

want to remove the col2 & col5 which have the sum amount equal to zero.

Comment: SQL can't make columns optional in a result. You need to write dynamic SQL in a stored procedure to do this.

Comment: It would be easier to do this by post-processing in a procedural language like PHP or Python.

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor design